# C - use libcurl to list imap sent mails

Tags: c, imap

I use libcurl library to get all email in sent mail box from url : imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/[Gmail]/Sent Mail .But it not run and show error :

```
curl_easy_perform() failed: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Please help me to check it . Thanks in advance. Toan Nguyen

```
struct string {
 char *ptr;
 size_t len;
};

void init_string(struct string *s) {
  s->len = 0;
  s->ptr = malloc(s->len+1);
  if (s->ptr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 s->ptr[0] = '\0';
}

size_t writefunc(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, struct string *s)
{
 size_t new_len = s->len + size*nmemb;
 s->ptr = realloc(s->ptr, new_len+1);
 if (s->ptr == NULL) {
   fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
memcpy(s->ptr+s->len, ptr, size*nmemb);
 s->ptr[new_len] = '\0';
 s->len = new_len;

 return size*nmemb;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
 CURL *curl;
 CURLcode res;  

 curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
   struct string s;
   init_string(&s); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_USERNAME,argv[1]);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_PASSWORD,argv[2]);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/%5BGmail%5D%2FSent%20Mail;UID=*");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

printf("%s\n", s.ptr);
free(s.ptr);

/* Check for errors */ 
 if(res != CURLE_OK)
 fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
        curl_easy_strerror(res));

/* always cleanup */
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that imap **s** :// is supported. See [CURLOPT_URL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTURL).

Comment: I use this to get inbox mail that is ok but sent mail box is not run.

Comment: That would have been very useful to include in your original question! In that case, it's probably the space in `/Sent Mail;`. Try [URL-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it, as `/Sent%20Mail;`.

Comment: The '[', ']' will probably require URL-encoding as well. Try something like `imaps%3A%2F%2Fimap.gmail.com%3A993%2F%5BGmail%5D%2FSent+Mail%3BUID%3D*`.

Comment: Okay, thanks all I can access to sent mail box ,and I try to get all mails by anyway but it 's not successful.

Comment: There is a limit in Gmail IMAP for how many messages it will return by default. See settings in Gmail in case you haven't set this to "unlimited" before.

Comment: By the way, you might want to do `curl_easy_setop(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);`. That way you'll see what your client and the gmail server are talking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your IMAPS URI. According to [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501), mailbox names with spaces must be enclosed between double quotes `"` when used with SELECT or any other IMAP command.

The following should work:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/\"[Gmail]/All Mail\"");
```